# mute And play the background song but not showing mute image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, avaudioplayer, uianimation

I am trying to play background song it get the success but I placed one play button and I want to change image of my button as per some condition, but it is not showing the mute image. How do I animate the button to do this. this is my code

//declared interface .h file

```
UIButton *volumeBtn;  
Bool volu;
```

declared in .m file
creating button on view

```
-(void)creating
 {
   //volumeBtn
    volumeBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
     [volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [volumeBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(volumeBtnClick)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    [volumeBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+9,self.view.frame.origin.y+15, 40, 40)];

     volumeBtn.layer.cornerRadius=20;
     volumeBtn.layer.masksToBounds=NO;
    [volumeBtn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
   [self.view addSubview:volumeBtn];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{


 [self creating];

}
```

animation purpose

```
-(void)anim
{
 CGPoint vlm = CGPointMake( 530.0f , volumeBtn.center.y);
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f];
            volumeBtn.center = vlm;

            [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(anim) withObject:self afterDelay:1];

}
```

when button click the song will stop and play

```
-(void)volumeBtnClick
{
    if (volu ==YES)
    {
        volumeBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]];

        [app.player stop];
        volu=NO;
    }
    else if(volu==NO)
    {
     volumeBtn.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume.png"]];
        [app.player play];
        volu=YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this instead of setting background color [volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: Do you wants to set mute image at first time when button clicked or second time??

Comment: first time i want volume image when i press the volume button it becomes mute image.But above code always showing volume image button only.

Comment: did you try this [volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal]; in volumeBtnClick method ???

Comment: may i put it as my answer?

Comment: Ya sure...your code is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is Correct just change Two Lines in your Method volumeBtnClick. setBackgroundImage instead of Its Background Color

```
[volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal]

[volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So your code will be

```
-(void)volumeBtnClick
{
if (volu ==YES)
{
    [volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mute.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal]

    [app.player stop];
    volu=NO;
}
else if(volu==NO)
{
 [volumeBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"volume.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [app.player play];
    volu=YES;
}
}
```